# Environments got messed up after Ubuntu update

Tags: python

I've updated Ubuntu to 20.04. After the update, when I ran `python manage.py runserver` i got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

I saw that pyhon 3.8 was installed with the update, so i tried running `python3.6 manage.py runserver` and got:

```
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
mtn.Image.image: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
    HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "python -m pip install Pillow".
```

I tried `pip3 install Pillow` and `pip3.6 install Pillow` and got `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.packaging.tags'`.
Anyone else had this problem after update?

Comment: Since this question is not strictly coding related, but system-environment related, I think it would be more suitable for [Unix & Linux Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), not sure though.

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv? You probably should be, so that you're not tied into the OS setup like this. If you are already, you might just need to update it to point to the new Python executable, which you might need to install. I'm not too familiar with virtualenvs though.